# Change title of OK button JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way to change the title of button OK in `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` for example i have a panel and i want to show it inside a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` like this

```
MyPanel pan = new MyPanel();

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, venteFam, 
        "Title of the panel", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

This show me this :

[image]

So what i need is to change **OK and cancel** title to another title, is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOptionPane.showOptionDialog, which lets you supply your own texts as an array instead of JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog :

```html
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
        "Do you like this answer?", 
        "Feedback", 
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        null, 
        new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"},
        "default");
```